# What is the complixity of simple Set, Get, toString function?

Tags: java

This is the first time that I've heard of complexity for simple function so I am confused.
Am I right?

This is my Class, I need to write the complexity  for each function but I think it's all O(1).

```
public class PolyNode
{
    private int _power;
    private double _coefficient;
    private PolyNode _next;

    public PolyNode (int power, double coefficient)
    {
        if (power < 0)
        {
            _power = 0;
            _coefficient = 0;
            _next = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _power = power;
            _coefficient = coefficient;
            _next = null;
        }
    }

    public PolyNode(int power, double coefficient,PolyNode next)
    {
        if (power < 0)
        {
            _power = 0;
            _coefficient = 0;
            _next = next._next;
        }
        else
        {
            _power = power;
            _coefficient = coefficient;
            _next = next._next;
        }
    }

    public PolyNode(PolyNode p)
    {
        _power = p._power;
        _coefficient = p._coefficient;
        _next = p._next;
    }

    public int getPower()
    {
        return _power;
    }

    public double getCoefficient()
    {
        return _coefficient;
    }

    public PolyNode getNext()
    {
        return _next;
    }

    public void setCoefficient (double coefficient)
    {
        _coefficient = coefficient;
    }

    public void setNext(PolyNode next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        String st = "";

        if (_coefficient == 0)
            return "";
        else if (_power == 0)
        {           
            st += _coefficient;
            return st;
        } 
        else if (_power == 1 && _coefficient != 1 && _coefficient != -1)
            return _coefficient + "x";
        else if (_coefficient == 1 || _coefficient == -1)
        {
            if (_coefficient == 1 && _power != 0)
            {
                if (_power == 1)
                    return "x";
                else
                    return "x^" + _power;
            }
            else if (_coefficient == 1 && _power == 0)
                return "1";
            else if (_coefficient == -1 && _power != 0)
                return "-x^" + _power;          
            else if (_coefficient == -1 && _power == 0)
                return "-1";
        }
            return _coefficient + "x^" +_power;         
    }
}
```

Comment: no loop, no recursion: O(1) sounds right.

Comment: Please follow proper Java naming conventions.. Also, anything that takes time to complete has a complexity.. Its just that we tend to ignore it in some cases..

Comment: The only thing I was questioning is `toString` which contains double to string conversion and string append but that is not affected by the input data so O(1) still seems right.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have any loops, I guess the complexity is O(1). If you have a for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){}
```

It will be O(N), and this:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
```

will be O(n*n)